# How to ungroupify list of object to list of another object using java8

Tags: arraylist, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a requirement where I need to convert a list of `Department` to  list of `DepartmentDetails` . Department has data for employees and managers grouped by id . How can I create a list of DepartmentDetails with segregated information?

```
 Class Department {
     private  int id ;
     private List<Employee> employee;
     private List<Manager> manager;
    }
    
    Class Employee {
      private int empId;
      private String empName;
    }
    
    Class Manager{
    private int manId;
    private String manName;
    }


   Class DepartmentDetails {
   private int id ;
   private String personType ;
   private int personId;
  }
```

Here , the id of Department Details remains same as Department id , personType has the value as Manager/Employee and personId has empId/manId.

One way to do this is to iterate over `List<Department>` and inside it , iterate over `List<Managers>` and `List<Employees>` , create required  `DepartmentDetail` object using setters and add in the final list. Is there any more elegant way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on why this class hierarchy is written. Ideally, `Manager` is also an `Employee`. `Department` can contain a single `List<Employee>` if this is done.

Also, `DepartmentDetails`  should have type `Integer` for `personId`.To answer your query with the existing structure, we can break down the problem into multiple smaller pieces.

1. Each `Department` can produce `List<DepartmentDetails>`.

   public class Department {

   ```
   private int id;
   private List<Employee> employee;
   private List<Manager> manager;

   public List<DepartmentDetails> toDepartmentDetails() {
       return Stream.concat(employee.stream().map(e -> DepartmentDetails.builder().id(this.id).personType(
                   "Employee")
               .personId(e.getEmpId()).build()),
           manager.stream().map(m -> DepartmentDetails.builder().id(this.id).personType("Manager")
               .personId(m.getManId()).build())).collect(Collectors.toList());
   }

   }
   ```
2. Use `flatMap` to convert `List<List<DepartmentDetails>>` to `List<DepartmentDetails>` while iterating through `List<Department>`

   ```
   List<DepartmentDetails> result =
           departments.stream().flatMap(department -> department.toDepartmentDetails().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

Comment: The dataType of personId was a typo . Have edited it . Thanks , this answer is what I need for my requirement.